# How can I quickly create many similar slots for a class?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I have the following classes, and more like them:

```
(defclass weapon ()
  ((base-slice-damage
    :documentation "Base slice damage dealt by weapon"
    :reader base-slice-damage
    :initform 0
    :initarg :base-slice-damage)
   (base-blunt-damage
    :reader base-blunt-damage
    :initform 0
    :initarg :base-blunt-damage)
   (base-pierce-damage
    :reader base-pierce-damage
    :initform 0
    :initarg :base-pierce-damage)))

(defclass dagger (weapon)
  ((base-slice-damage
    :initform 3)
   (base-pierce-damage
    :initform 6)))

(defclass attack ()
  ((slice-damage-dealt
    :initarg :slice-damage-dealt
    :reader slice-damage-dealt)
   (blunt-damage-dealt
    :initarg :blunt-damage-dealt
    :reader blunt-damage-dealt)
   (pierce-damage-dealth
    :initarg :pierce-damage-dealt
    :reader pierce-damage-dealt)))
```

As you can see, there is a lot of repetition. For two of the classes, my slots all have the same option and vary only by whether they're slice, blunt, or pierce.

I've thought about using a macro to define attribute classes and then just mixing those in. This is what I have so far:

```
(defmacro defattrclass (attr-name &body class-options)
  `(defclass ,(symb attr-name '-attr) ()
     ((,attr-name
       ,@class-options))))
```

But this really doesn't go far enough.

---

Edit:

I've come up with this, though I'm not completely happy with it:

```
(defmacro defattrclass (attr-name &body class-options)
  `(defclass ,(symb attr-name '-attr) ()
     ((,attr-name
       ,@class-options))))

(defmacro defattrclasses (attr-names &body class-options)
  `(progn
     ,@(loop for attr-name in attr-names collect
            `(defattrclass ,attr-name ,@class-options))))
```

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/qwy5o/how_can_i_quickly_create_many_similar_slots_for_a/  (it's good netiquette to be explicit if you're asking questions in two places at the same time.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite 100% coverage of the features you want, but I've been using this macro for a while:

```
(defmacro defclass-default (class-name superclasses slots &rest class-options)
  "Shorthand defclass syntax; structure similar to defclass
  Pass three values: slot-name, :initform, and :documentation
  Everything else gets filled in to standard defaults"
  `(defclass 
     ,class-name 
     ,superclasses 
     ,(mapcar (lambda (x) `( ,(first x)
                             :accessor ,(first x)
                             :initarg ,(intern (symbol-name (first x)) "KEYWORD")
                             :initform ,(second x)
                             :documentation ,(third x)))
              slots)
     ,@class-options))
```

To use:

```
CL-USER> 
(defclass-default weapon ()
  ((base-slice-damage 0 "Base slice damage dealt by a weapon")
   (base-blunt-damage 0 "Needs a doc")
   (base-pierce-damage 0 "Needs a doc")))
#<STANDARD-CLASS WEAPON>
CL-USER>
```

Comment: This looks helpful, thanks. I'm wondering if it'd be too crazy to allow variation in the slots? For example, in some cases I want my to only create a reader instead of an accessor.

Comment: Up to you; find that right intersection between the language and your problem; with macros, you really can do whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it looks like you need a class `damage` with three fields (`slice`, `blunt`, `pierce`). You can use that class inside `weapon`, `attack` etc.

Comment: I was thinking about something along those lines. However, I'm also creating slots like "slice-damage-received" and other variations.

Comment: Might get some traction with multiple inheritance (e.g., to make slot mixins)